# using i18n with rails 3 problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, locale, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got some form for user registration and want to localize it via locales yml files. Especially errors from validations.

For example, locale file:

```
tr:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user: 
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "can't be blank"
```

it will return: `name can't be blank` in errors area:

```
<% @user.errors.each do |error| -%>
  <p><%= error %></p>
<% end -%>
```

Next step I want to create is to rename **name** attribute (and others) like that (**this is what don't work**):

```
tr:
  attributes:
    user:
      name: "Real name"
```

to get this error after validation: `Real name can't be blank`

So where I should locale attribute names to translate them in error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tr:
    activerecord:
        attributes:
            modelname:
                attributename: "translation"
```

Substituting *modelname* with the name of your model, and *attributename* with the name of the attribute you want to provide a translation for, here ***name***.

Comment: no reaction. I've tried to use _labels.model.attributes_, _helpers.model.attributes_ etc - no results

Comment: I've figured it out, that Rails 3 don't use human_attribute_name by default in errors listing.